# Navigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on this shopping app which uses radio buttons. The customer should be able to select a radio button and go it by clicking the 'select button'.
Can anyone help me get get started.
the code is below.

I hope this makes sense to everyone.  I have made a page for each of the radio buttons. pages are name the same as the buttons.

```
@Composable
fun MyRadioGroup() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    val radioOptions = listOf(
        "Dollar Store", "Fred Myers",
        "Wall Mart", "SafeWay", "Sherm's", "CostCo", "Other"
    )
    val (selectedOption, onOptionSelected) = remember {
        mutableStateOf(radioOptions[1])
    }
    Scaffold() {

        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)) },
        )
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 160.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Select Store from List Below")
        Divider()
        Text(
            text = "Then push the 'Select'")
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        radioOptions.forEach { text ->
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(top = 8.dp)
                    .selectable(
                        selected = (text == selectedOption),
                        onClick = { onOptionSelected(text) }
                    )
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            ) {
                RadioButton(
                    selected = (text == selectedOption),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 12.dp),

                    onClick = {
                        onOptionSelected(text)

                    }
                )
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(start = 24.dp, top = 640.dp)
    
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {
            TODO()


        }) {
            Text(text = "Select")

        }
        
    }
}
```

The 'select' button is near the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 0):

First create a sealed class *Screen* to link radio buttons text to composable as recommended by Google like this:

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String, val label: String){
object MyRadioGroup: Screen(route = "myRadioGroup", label = "APP NAME")
object DollarStore: Screen(route = "Dollar Store", label = "Dollar Store")
object FreedMyers: Screen(route = "Fred Myers", label = "FreedMyers")}
```

then modify *NavHost* or *AnimatedNavHost*(if you are using accompanist's *Navigatio Animatation* library as:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        val navController = rememberNavController()

        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
            NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.MyRadioGroup.route){
                composable(Screen.MyRadioGroup.route){
                    MyRadioGroup(navController = navController)
                }
                composable(Screen.DollarStore.route){
                    //Call here the associated composable function
                    DollarStore()
                }
                composable(Screen.FreedMyers.route){
                    //Call here the associated composable function
                    FreedMyers()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Finally add some code to *MyRadioGroup* Composable

```
fun MyRadioGroup(navController: NavController) {
val radioOptions = listOf(
    "Dollar Store", "Fred Myers",
    "Wall Mart", "SafeWay", "Sherm's", "CostCo", "Other"
)
val (selectedOption, onOptionSelected) = remember {
    mutableStateOf(radioOptions[1])
}
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)) },
        )
    }
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Select Store from List Below")
            Divider()
            Text(text = "Then push the 'Select'")
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            radioOptions.forEach { text ->
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(top = 8.dp)
                        .selectable(
                            selected = (text == selectedOption),
                            onClick = { onOptionSelected(text) }
                        )
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                ) {
                    RadioButton(
                        selected = (text == selectedOption),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 12.dp),
                        onClick = { onOptionSelected(text) }
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = text,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 24.dp, top = 24.dp)

        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(selectedOption) //navigate to selected route
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Select")
            }
        }
    }
}}
```